# Retrieve data from database and map to model

Tags: c#, angular, database, entity-framework

I have a 'GET' request to my API pointing to the 'MapController' which promotes the 'GetAllProducts' method.

I want this method to retrieve all records within my database and then return this data as a list of objects and then provide this to the client.

I am having some trouble figuring out how to map my database schema to my model. this is my current attempt.

controller class:

```
    public class MapController : ApiController
    {

        private string SQLServerToUse = "34.255.206.221";
        private string SQLServerDB = "HCT";
        private string SQLServerPWD = "pass";
        private string SQLServerUser = "user";

        public IEnumerable<Map> GetAllProducts()
        {
            //set the connection string
            string connString = "Data Source=" + SQLServerToUse + ";Initial Catalog=" + SQLServerDB + ";User ID=" + SQLServerUser + ";Password=" + SQLServerPWD + ";";

            //variables to store the query results
            List<Map> maps = new List<Map>();

            //sql connection object
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open(); Console.WriteLine("connection open");
                string query = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.Map";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var map = new Map();
                            map.Map_Data_ID = reader.GetInt32("Map_Data_ID");
                            map.County = reader.GetString("County");
                            map.Color = reader.GetString("Color");
                            maps.Add(map);
                        }

                    }
                }                   
            }

            return maps;
        }         

    }
}
```

Model:

```
   public class Map
{
    public string Map_Data_ID { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Database schema:

[image]

Expected format to present to ui:

```
[
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 122,
        "County": "West Yorkshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    },
    {
        "Map_Data_ID": 167,
        "County": "Wiltshire",
        "Color": "#d45faa"
    }
]
```

as you can see it expects an int as the paramater.
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? Are you getting stuck on anything in particular?

Comment: well i was just wondering if there is a better more readable or efficient solution. That and i am currently getting a 'cannot convert string to int' error on these lines.  map.Map_Data_ID = reader.GetInt32("Map_Data_ID");
                            map.County = reader.GetString("County");
                            map.Color = reader.GetString("Color");

Comment: I can't see the advantage of `entity-framework` in your code, since you are using sql commands directly. Any way there are tools like https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, there are some things I can note:

1. In an n-tier architecture, your controller would not contain data access logic directly. Instead, data access would be contained in another class, which would be (ideally) injected into your controller via dependency injection.
2. You can use an ORM such as [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), which removes the need to write raw SQL in your code, and instead uses LINQ.
3. Without using an ORM, and without separating your data access logic from the controller, what you have is fine, especially if you're just learning.
4. The fact that your table's `ID` column is an `INT` type, but in your `Map` class you have the type as `string`, is a problem. Change that to `int` and that should resolve the error.
5. The **cannot convert string to int** error is actually caused by `GetInt32` and `GetString` methods on the `SqlDataReader` type accepting `int` as a parameter, which is the ordinal of the column. So if column 0 is the `ID` then pass `0` to `reader.GetInt32` and so on. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I seem to be getting that error for all 3 of the parameters. Thanks for you information i will look into entity framework. Sounds like the best possible solution. I added a screenshot to my original post

Comment: @ashleyg I updated my answer. Please see the new bullet point 5, which is the true cause of the errors in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, you should first create a `DbContext` associated with your database and define your model class in the correct way and create `DbSet` in the context. With all these done, you can use the context to CRUD your data instead of writing SQL.

For details, you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)